# Conformality of a map f is invariant under parametric transform

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization

Let *S, S** be parametric surfaces given by parametrizations $\overrightarrow{r}$: *U* $\rightarrow$ *S* and $\overrightarrow{r*}$: *U** $\rightarrow$ *S**.
Is the conformality of a map *f* : *S* $\rightarrow$ *S** invariant under a proper parametric transform   ($\phi(\hat{u},\hat{v})$,$\psi(\hat{u},\hat{v})$) of $\overrightarrow{r}$ from  $\hat{U}$ to *U*?
Prove or disprove?

Comment: What do you mean by a parametric transform? How do you define conformality? Suppose that $f: U\to V$ is a conformal map between two domains in the plane and $h: W\to U$ is an arbitrary diffeomorphism. Is the composition $f\circ h$ necessarily conformal?